# Event for DOM text selection, NOT in Input or TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to find a Javascript event for when the user highlights paragraph text on a web page with the mouse.  Once the text is highlighted, I can get to it with `window.getSelection()`.

This is **not about** trapping events within an `<input type="text">` or `<textarea>`, that is easy.

I'm interested in when the user highlights text that would be controlled with the CSS `user-select: all;` or  `user-select: none;`.

Bonus for a jQuery answer. ;-)

Comment: `document.getSelection()`

Comment: Also, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Answer (score -1):

You can bind to `mouseup`:

```
<body>
<div style='user-select: all'>
  all all all all all all all all all all all 
</div>
<br>
<div style='user-select: none'>
  none none none none none none none none none 
</div>
<br>
<div style='user-select: text'>
  text text text text text text text text text
</div>  
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
    if( window.getSelection().toString().length){
        window.alert (window.getSelection().toString());
        window.getSelection().empty();
    }
})
</script>
```